Should I add components.d.ts to gitignore?
components.d.ts is auto-generated by unplugin-vue-components when dev server starts. It often cause conflicts when merging PRs in the projects I have participated in.
components.d.ts looks like:
/* eslint-disable */
// @ts-nocheck
// Generated by unplugin-vue-components
// Read more: https://github.com/vuejs/core/pull/3399
export {}

/* prettier-ignore */
declare module 'vue' {
  export interface GlobalComponents {
    NA: typeof import('naive-ui')['NA']
    NAlert: typeof import('naive-ui')['NAlert']
    NButton: typeof import('naive-ui')['NButton']
    NConfigProvider: typeof import('naive-ui')['NConfigProvider']
    NDivider: typeof import('naive-ui')['NDivider']
    NFlex: typeof import('naive-ui')['NFlex']
    NForm: typeof import('naive-ui')['NForm']
    NFormItem: typeof import('naive-ui')['NFormItem']
    NSkeleton: typeof import('naive-ui')['NSkeleton']
    NSwitch: typeof import('naive-ui')['NSwitch']
    NText: typeof import('naive-ui')['NText']
  }
}

It's almost a list of components that I've used, and it doesn't seem to affect the build. Different from lockfiles, components.d.ts are only exists for TypeScript, does not "lock" anything, and its content is relevant to the user's environment. So whether it is considered as "history" is an issue.
I searched components.d.ts file on GitHub and found 15.4k results. (make me doubt myself) However, when searching components.d.ts, I found 0 result. Maybe GitHub don't index .gitignore.

Could anyone please help me create & add unplugin-vue-components tag? Sadly I don't have enough rep :(

If a tag doesn't exist yet, that's probably because it's not in demand. "conflicts in some of the projects I have participated in" - in which way? The question lacks the context. If it causes a problem for a lib then it should probably be added to npmignore instead. If the lack of the file causes problems too then it needs to be investigated further. At which point the file is generated?

If the absence of it doesn't cause problems and the presence does then probably ignore it, you can undo it. Are the conflicts the only kind of problems? And it's unknown what is your setup and under which conditions the problems could occur. Do you use vue-tsc? Because this is what could be affected by it. And it's often used as a script to type check the project like build: vue-tsc --noEmit && vite build, so components.d.ts may not exist at the time it runs. If the absence causes a problem for git clone ... && npm i && npm run build then ignoring it would be a mistake

If you want your components.d.ts file to be versioned and keep track of its history, then don't add it to gitignore. But generally, generated files should be added to .gitignore.
Reference
